# Remove the first two letters of each line on a txt file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

Basically I generated a text file through `wmic` with all of present windows updates on one of my client systems.

The text file comes up as:

```
HotFixID
KB3140768
KB3150513
KB...(and so on)
```

So, I wish to execute a command through cmd (even if I have to grab some "outside" tool to get it done), in order to remove the `KB` from the beginning of each line, and leaving me only with the numbers.

I managed to "jump" the `HotFixID` with:

```bat
for /f "skip=1" (...)
```

But I can't manage to remove the `KB*`.

My idea is, to bulk remove all windows updates at once, over cmd/batch file.

Comment: Please edit your question with all of your existing code.

Comment: use `for /f "skip=1delims=KB" %%A in (...) do echo %%A`  to strip of `KB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution (for cmd):

```bat
for /f "skip=1 delims=KB" %A IN (your_file.txt) do @echo %A >> your_new.txt
```

For batch file you have to try:

```bat
for /f "skip=1 delims=KB" %%A IN (your_file.txt) do echo %%A >> your_new.txt
```

- `skip=1` option skips the first line of your file which is `HotFixID`.
- `delims=KB` option doesn't parse `K` and `B` into tokens.

For better understanding the `for` command/loop please type `for /?` in a fresh cmd.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate text file, but can parse wmic output directly, cmd line:

```
> for /f "skip=1delims=KB " %A in ('wmic qfe get HotfixID') do @for /f "delims= " %B in ("%A") do @echo:%B
4100347
4343669
...
```

In a batch file

```
@Echo off
for /f "skip=1delims=KB " %%A in ('wmic qfe get HotfixID'
   ) do for /f "delims= " %%B in (%%A) do echo:%%B
```

This simple approach works as leading delimiters are ignored and
provided the content to parse doesn't contain any of the letters used as delims.

Comment: It seems that there is an extra blank line emitted at the end. How can that be overcome?

Comment: Added a space as an additional delimiter to strip the trailing space off. See changed answer.

Comment: Sorry missed the old wmic flaw to insert a cr cr lf sequence. Use a 2nd nestes for to overcome thos.